# Using Squish with python, where the text of a print is printed?

Tags: python-2.7, squish

In a python script that is called by the test case, I writed a `print`.

Where the output of a the function print is printed ?

Note : I use Squish 6.2.0 with python 2.7, but any answer to the question will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the text printed by the python `print`, click on 'Show View', then 'Runner/Server Log'.

[image]

Comment: In Squish you can also use `test.log()` instead of print function